# How to draw a line between two zy planes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ, I define two zy planes at two different x positions. I want to draw a line from one specific point on one plane to another specific point on the other plane. How can I draw that line?

Note: The units need to be in cm.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0.6cm]
\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}
    \foreach \j in {-2,...,2}
        \node at (\i cm, \j cm) [circle,fill,inner sep=0.1cm,color=green] {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0.3cm]
\foreach \i in {-1,...,1}
    \foreach \j in {-1,...,1}
        \node at (\i cm, \j cm) [circle,fill,inner sep=0.1cm,color=red] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can the planes be defined in-place close to the coordinates? The following code does not produce the desired results yet:

```latex
\draw (0cm,1cm)[canvas is zy plane at x=0.3 cm] -- (0cm,2cm) [canvas is zy plane at x=0.6cm];
```

Formulating this problem in 3D coordinates would work but requires a lot of calculation, which I want to avoid.

(Sorry, I cannot upload the picture resulting from this minimal working example because an error occurs on the server.)

Comment: Please note that `canvas is zy plane=0.6cm` does not place the plane at `x=0.6cm`, but at `x=0.6cm/1pt=17.07182` : `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0.6cm]
 \fill (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{scope}
\draw[red] (0.6cm,0) circle[radius=3pt];
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{0.6cm}
\typeout{\myx}
\draw[blue] (\myx,0) circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.
So there is no surprise that this does not match "outside" coordinates.

Comment: You can also place named coordinates in the planes and connect those.

Comment: That `x=0.6cm` gets converted, resolved one confusion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The crucial hint was given in the comments by @TikZling:

> You can also place named coordinates in the planes and connect those.

The following code produces the desired image:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0.6cm]
\foreach \i [count=\cnta] in {-2,...,2}
    \foreach \j [count=\cntb] in {-2,...,2}
        \node (u\cnta\cntb) at (\i cm, \j cm) [circle,fill,inner sep=0.1cm,color=green] {};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0.3cm]
\foreach \i [count=\cnta] in {-1,...,1}
    \foreach \j [count=\cntb] in {-1,...,1}
        \node (v\cnta\cntb) at (\i cm, \j cm) [circle,fill,inner sep=0.1cm,color=red] {};
\end{scope}

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,5}
        \foreach \k in {1,...,3}
            \foreach \l in {1,...,3}
                \draw (u\i\j) -- (v\k\l);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```